# libgdx actor input listener after scalling

Tags: input, libgdx, listener, scale, actor

I have a problem with libgdx actor listener. First of all I have to say that it was working correctly. I had a problem with button scalling. Nice description with screenshots here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15535&p=67247#p67247

After adding PPMs (pixel per meter)

```
jumpButton.setPosition(Runner.SCREEN_WIDTH/PPM - jumpButton.getWidth()/PPM - 20/PPM, jumpButton.getHeight()/PPM + 20/PPM + 40/PPM);
```

and size:

```
jumpButton.setWidth(jumpButton.getWidth()/PPM);
jumpButton.setHeight(jumpButton.getHeight()/PPM);
```

and modifying my guiStage a bit by adding:

```
guiStage.setViewport(guiStretchViewport);
guiCamera.setToOrtho(false, Runner.SCREEN_WIDTH/PPM, Runner.SCREEN_HEIGHT/PPM);
```

Problem is solved because it's scaling using PPM like any other object in the game world.

The problem is with listener which was working before(!) but now I think it didn't scale down like the texture for some reason. I set bounds, i set size and I have no idea what's wrong.

This is my button:

```
    jumpButton = new Image((Texture)ResourcesManager.getInstance().getResource(ScreenType.SCREEN_GAME, "gfx/game/characters/buttons/jumpButton.png"));
    jumpButton.setPosition(Runner.SCREEN_WIDTH/PPM - jumpButton.getWidth()/PPM - 20/PPM, jumpButton.getHeight()/PPM + 20/PPM + 40/PPM);
    jumpButton.setWidth(jumpButton.getWidth()/PPM);
    jumpButton.setHeight(jumpButton.getHeight()/PPM);
    jumpButton.setBounds(jumpButton.getX(), jumpButton.getY(), jumpButton.getWidth(), jumpButton.getHeight());
    jumpButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            world.player.jump();
            return true;
        }
    });
    guiStage.addActor(jumpButton);
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In provided link someone answered me and he was right.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    guiStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

This done the thing:)